Does a change in the trace of the stress-energy tensor when a particle passes through an event horizon violate energy conditions?
When a particle crosses the event horizon of a black hole, the trace of its stress-energy tensor undergoes a change in sign, prompting questions about potential violations of the strong energy condition which prohibits negative energy density measurements by any observer. This raises a broader question about whether the trace of a stress-energy tensor describing a physical object can ever be positive (which corresponds to a negative Ricci scalar through $R=-\kappa T$). How about the other energy conditions?

Note about the SEC: try fulfilling it with flat spacetime $g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(c^2,-1,-1,-1)$ and a nonzero cosmological constant. The SEC is violated (but not the other energy conditions). Most generally the WEC is taken to be the most important in validating a given situation in the context of the four energy conditions.


When a particle crosses the event horizon of a black hole, its stress-energy tensor undergoes a change in sign

This statement is not a valid statement. The stress-energy tensor is a tensor, not a scalar. So it doesn't have a sign.
In a particular basis or coordinate chart it does have components that have signs. Those components can easily change signs in different charts. That should not be interpreted as the tensor changing sign.
Now, a stress energy tensor certainly can change due to any number of a variety of local physical processes. Hence, it could change while crossing the event horizon. However, in the absence of such a local physical process, merely crossing the event horizon will not change the invariants. Locally the event horizon is simply a null surface which passes across the system at the speed of light, like any other null surface.

Thanks for the point. I made a typo error which is corrected now. My question is about the trace of the stress-energy tensor.

That doesn't change unless some physical process happens to change it. That is what I was trying to say in the last paragraph

If a particle crosses the event horizon with a small amount of momentum, the sign of the tt and rr components of the metric changes. Consequently, the trace of the energy-momentum tensor would also change.

I don’t think that is true. I would need to see a derivation since it goes against what I know of the actual math of GR
